# Flutter: Playing sound from UInt8List in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, media-player

I have a `UInt8List` which contains sound byte data (can be mp3 or wav).

I am trying to build a small sound player component. However I found no way to put the byte data into a audio player plugin.

1. Is there a supporting plugin which supports loading from bytes for both platforms?
2. Is there a way to simulate a local file without need to save the data as a real file in the file system? The idea would be to create a "simulated" local file and put into a player's `loadFromFile` method.
3. Another idea was to create some kind of simulated network resourse, maybe creating an URI (`Uri.dataFromBytes`) and put this into a player's `loadFromNetwork` method...
4. ???

I tested several approaches but none worked.

I really wonder why this seems to be very difficult although I believe that must be a very standard use case. Reading from file or network resource is easy, but already having the byte data...

Any hint appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Maybe a possible solution would be using two different plugins. There's a plugin, which supports this for Android. Do you know one, which has the support for iOS?

Comment: have you found a good plugin?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(sound_path_1); //load sound from assets
Uint8List  soundbytes = bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes);
await player.play(BytesSource(soundbytes));
```

another way

```
var sound_path_1 = "/data/user/0/.../1680008060582.mp3";
File tempFile = File(sound_path_1);
await player.play(DeviceFileSource(tempFile.path));
```

Comment: What is player in your code? Which package is it from?

Comment: Looks like https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers